# Difference between matrix and animation rotation

Tags: android

If I want to rotate an imageview. Would I use Matrix rotation or animation rotation? What would be the difference?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the purpose. An animation would usually be a 1 time thing, and will be done by performing some predefined action. A matrix would be used for multitouch interactions which the user might want to make. They serve 2 different purposes usually. What type of rotation are you talking about? If you need your user to manually rotate, you will need to use multitouch. If you just want to show some cool animation, then just this is not necessary.

The cool thing about the matrix is that you can store the matrix in your database and retrieve it later. The matrix can then be applied to your image view so that it displays correctly.

Comment: Thanks Dhruv. This is a very good answer. Well, I am looking for continues animations. Bascially as long as the person is touching an image view, the image will keep rotating. I guess you are saying Matrix, wouldn't animation do the same? Cons?

Comment: You should do this using animations and the onTouch event. You need to detect when the person has pressed down until he presses up, keep animating. You will need to use the animation listener callbacks too (e.g., onAnimationStart).

Comment: Dhruv then what do you mean by use. Matrix for multi touch?

Comment: More like the matrix can be stored and used later to reapply your transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix rotation is basically used in `Canvas` applications because of [the matrix class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) is "*a 3x3 matrix for transforming coordinates*" - that can be defined from rectangles, circles etc.

Animating views in Android are usually done by the [`Animation` API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) -- *go with that*.

Comment: From your answer, it seems that I should always go with animations. Is this true? I am looking for continues animations. Bascially as long as the person is touching an image view, the image will keep rotating. Do I go for Animations

Comment: @Snake: Nah, more like the purpose of the `Animation` API was to create an easy-going opportunity to create animations without the need to deal with matrices. The `Matrix` class can be used for different shapes, but I think that's not the case in your current situation. You can set a repeat mode for your `Animation` object if you'd want to, e.g. infinite amount of animations.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really speak to the differences, but I had an easy time creating a simple rotating animation for a gold star ImageView using the regular Animation class:

**MainActivity.java (*in onCreate()*):**

```
mGoldStar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.goldStar);
...
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
mGoldStar.startAnimation(rotation);
```

**rotate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="1500" />
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I know how to do animations. I love that it is easy. But I am looking to know when "not" to use it